# Fail calling back about protocol and delegate by Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I m confuse about call back using protocol and delegate.
The problem is. I have two viewcontrollers `vcA & vcB`
 and `vcA` have a tableView, `vcB` have a button.
vcA click the cell to `vcB`.
Then I want to click the button in `vcB` and do the following two things.

```
1.vcA tableView reloadData.
2.vcB popViewcontroller To vcA.
```

I can't understand how to solve this issue.
Have any sample to teach me?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to use `delegate/protocol` ? You can only show one VC at a time, so you could do it step by step: `vcB.handleButton { popVC to vcA }` and in vcA you can do your realoadData in `viewDidAppear()`

Comment: because I want to figure out this topic.

Comment: I think that @SH_Khan answer is what you are looking for

Comment: @Sandu You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the delegate solution , but it's better to put the `self.tableView.reloadData()` method inside `viewDidAppear` , as it's being called when you pop VcB

```
class VcA: UIViewController ,TableRefresh {

    func reloadTable()
    {
        // reload here
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let des = segue.destination as! VcB

         des.delegate = self

    }
}

protocol TableRefresh {
    func reloadTable()
}

class VcB: UIViewController {
    var delegate: TableRefresh?

    @IBAction func closeClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.reloadTable()
        // pop here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you to help me figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1: Put `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear()` and then just pop vcB

2: When you are pushing vcB you create a reference to it and then in vcB you have a listener that you apply to the reference. like so:

```
    class viewControllerB: UIViewController {
          var reloadTableView: (() -> ())

          @objc func buttonPressed() {
             reloadTableView()
             self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

          }
    }
```

And then:

```
let vcB = viewControllerB()
vcB.reloadTableView = {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
present(vcB, animated: true)
```

3: Do as Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this could work for you:**

```
 class vcA : UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }

class vcB : UIViewController {

    @IBAction fun button(bin : UIButton){
    self.navigationController.popViewController(true)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call the methods of any VC objects if it's not in your memory.

For the first time, it vcB will not be in memory. Hence the object of the same is not in existence.

If you really want to call a function of that class and if its feasible crate an object of vcB and call the method.
or you might try a shared object of the VC and keep on using the same if it's feasible. you may post exact scenario so that people can suggest something better

Answer (score 0):

Your `vcA` has a reference to the `vcB`, so you are able to write something like this in the vcA

```
class vcA {
    var vcB: vcB?
    ...
    vcB?.doSmth()
    ....
}
```

but there is no way for you to call `vcA` from the `vcB` since it doesn't have a reference to it. So to let `vcA` know that something happened in `vcB` or to call some function from `vcB` you can do several things.
Delegates, Key-Value Observing, Reactive Programming and some others.
Since you asked for the delegates solution lets stick to it.

The general idea behind delegates is as the name says to `delegate` someone else to do something. In your case, you want to delegate button click handling to the `vcA`. To do so, you will need a couple of things.

Next steps are just the implementation of the idea described above.

```
class VcA {
    var vcB: VcB?
    ...
    vcB?.delegate = self
    ...
    vcB?.doSmth()
    ....
}

extension VcA: VcBDelegate {
    func buttonIsClicked() {
        // reload data
        // pop vcB
    }
}

protocol VcBDelegate: class {
    func buttonIsClicked()
}

class VcB {
    var delegate: VcBDelegate?
    ...
    // when the button is clicked
    // delegate handling to someone who is 'listening' for this event
    self.delegate?.buttonIsClicked()
    ...
}
```

Notice how `delegate` in VcB is optional, meaning that if no one is signed as a delegate for VcB, the event will simply be ignored.